# EmberJS Loading Substate: What logic does it use to climb the route hierarchy to find the loading template?

Tags: templates, ember.js, promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around Ember's loading substate.  According to the Guides...

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

...the loading substate will show while the model is being resolved, and if a loading template doesn't exist for the current route, it will climb the route hierarchy until it finds a 'loading' template.  So I defined a 'loading' template, but it doesn't always show.

Here an example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/junop/2

First, when the page loads, the loading template doesn't show even when the ApplicationRoute's model is being resolved.  Then if you go to 'books', the loading template will show.  So going from 'index' to 'books' will always show the loading template.  But them going to a specific 'book' (e.g. Three Little Pigs in my example) doesn't show the loading template.  Finally, going to 'book' from 'books' doesn't show the loading template, even though it will if you go from 'index' to 'books'.  I can't make sense of all of this.  What logic does Ember use to climb the hierarchy to show the loading template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different things related to loading.  The loading route vs the loading action.

Each resource with at least one child (the root included, aka application route) has a loading route.  Ember won't hit the loading route unless the parent resource has already   been rendered.  This means it's less useful for the first load, and more useful for transitions.

http://jsbin.com/cajivava/5/edit

No worry, there are loading actions!  Each time a model hook is taking some time to resolve, it will send an action to that route, which will traverse up the router until handeled (or if you handle it, then return true, which will send it up the tree).  This can be super useful for magical loading, or for first time loads.  Just remember (and I show it in this example, that if you don't handle the loading action at a particular route it will be passed up to application).

http://jsbin.com/cajivava/6/edit

Now you can just hack it into a different place in the application route, since it's a special route that's only ever loaded once.  A mixture of the two is usually the best plan if you have a long loading app in the beginning.

http://jsbin.com/cajivava/4/edit

It's easiest to think about transitions in the sense of the outlets. The section to be rendered is stalled, so the outlet where it's going to rendered into, transitions to the loading route.  Once it's complete, it navigates to books index.

In the example below, try clicking on cows. It's a resource 2 deep and books resolves immediately (the resource in the middle), but the transition is stalled on cows, so our outlet where we're going to render all of the newness transitions to the loading route.

http://jsbin.com/buyaxipowi/1/edit

Individual loading routes housed in their own resource require the resource itself to be resolved before you can hit it's loading route:

http://jsbin.com/niwerikuli/1/edit

Comment: That's interesting.  You added a books/loading template, so that's what gets rendered when you go from books.index to book and vice versa.  books/loading also gets rendered when going from index to books.index.  That all makes sense now.  In my http://emberjs.jsbin.com/junop/2 example where I haven't defined a books/loading template, it renders the root loading template when going from index to books.index.  Why would that be? Because the model needs to be resolved in books.index and not books, I would think that no loader would get rendered because books/index is not defined.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with a whiteboard.  It's easiest to think about it in the sense of the outlets.  The section to be rendered in the application outlet is stalled, so it renders the application loading.  Once it's complete, it navigates to books index.

Comment: This should show a similar thing, try clicking on cows.  It's a resource 2 deep, and the books now resolves immediately, but the transition is stalled on cows, so our outlet where we're going to render all of the newness turns into the loading route, http://jsbin.com/simufore/1/edit

Comment: Interesting.  books now resolves immediately, so I would have thought that the books template would get rendered immediately and then look for books/loading template to place into the books outlet while the transition is stalled on cows.  This is what happens as soon as you add a books/loading template (as shown here: http://jsbin.com/simufore/2/edit), but it turns out that if books/loading doesn't exist, then the transition gets stalled at the nearest loading template up the route hierarchy.  I understand it now.  Thank you.

Comment: I just discovered that enabling '/# Routes' tab of the Ember Inspector actually changes the behavior of the loading substate.  To demonstrate this, load @kingpin2K's example http://jsbin.com/simufore/1 in Chrome WITHOUT the Ember Inspector open.  Click between the 'Home' and 'Cows' links and every time you click 'Cows', you'll see a spinner.  Now open the Ember Inspector and go to the '/# Routes' tab.  Now do the same thing (click 'Home' and 'Cows') and you'll notice that the spinner no longer appears when you click 'Cows'. The inconsistency in behavior had me really confused.